# RadioBox groups not appearing as selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a site with AngularJS and am creating a survey to gather user information on the registration page. Each question in the survey contains four radio boxes, and the user must select one. Each radio box has a value from 0-3. This is the HTML for the page:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <div class="row 50%" align="left">
        <fieldset class="radiogroup">
            <legend>Data Structures</legend>
                <ul>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="0" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Not familiar with what data structures are.</label></li>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="1" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Can explain and use Arrays</label></li>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="2" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Familiar with the space and time</label></li>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="3" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Knowledge of advanced data structures</label></li>
                </ul>                             
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="row 50%" align="left">
        <fieldset class="radiogroup">
            <legend>Data Structures Test</legend>
                <ul>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="0" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio">Not familiar with what data structures are.</label></li>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="1" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio">Can explain and use Arrays</label></li>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="2" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio">Familiar with the space and time tradeoffs</label></li>
                <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="3" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio">Knowledge of advanced data structures</label></li>
                </ul>                             
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="button" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the `submitForm()` function:

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
      console.log("Data Structures Value " + $scope.dataStructures);
      console.log("Algorithms Value " + $scope.algorithms);
    };
```

So far, this code is working. I can select a value in the first group (dataStructures) and I can select a value in the second group (algorithms) and the choices selected are printed out as expected. The problem is that once another a radiobox from a different group is selected, the first group's option becomes deselected, like so:

[image: Select One...]

---

[image: ...And its done]

What is surprising to me is that the console still prints the correct values for the items selected (in the case of these images, 2 and 1).

How can I make it so that the selection from the first group is retained when the user selects something in another group? I would like to do this without using a form within a form, because the code I current have doing Auth is not really working with that setup. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a different name for each group of radio buttons

Comment: @WayneEllery So each `fieldset` tag should have a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each set of radio buttons should have a different `name` value.

For example you could do something like this:

```
    <fieldset class="radiogroup">
        <legend>Data Structures</legend>
            <ul>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="0" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Not familiar with what data structures are.</label></li>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="1" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Can explain and use Arrays</label></li>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="2" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Familiar with the space and time</label></li>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="3" ng-model="$parent.dataStructures" type="radio" name="optradio">Knowledge of advanced data structures</label></li>
            </ul>                             
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="radiogroup">
        <legend>Data Structures Test</legend>
            <ul>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="0" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio1">Not familiar with what data structures are.</label></li>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="1" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio1">Can explain and use Arrays</label></li>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="2" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio1">Familiar with the space and time tradeoffs</label></li>
            <li><label class="radio-inline"><input value="3" ng-model="$parent.algorithms" type="radio" name="optradio1">Knowledge of advanced data structures</label></li>
            </ul>                             
    </fieldset>
```

This would allow each set of buttons to retain its own value.